# Python "move semantics"

Tags: python, multithreading, move-semantics

I have a main thread which needs to flush a buffer to disk periodically, so every time I create a new Thread to run json.dump(buffer). But immediately after this I need to clear the buffer, so is there "move semantics" in Python which lets me do this without having to make a deep copy of it?

Comment: Why would you need move semantics?

Comment: I want to pass the buffer as an argument to the other thread and clear it immediately after, so I'd either have to deep copy, move the buffer to the argument, or move a new object to the buffer.

Comment: I'm still not following. Python passes around references in the first place, so there is never any need to copy. Extraneous references will get cleaned up when they're no longer in use.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! For some reason I thought buffer=[] would copy it in...

Comment: Any luck here?  I've been wondering the same thing. Hate copying if not needed.

Comment: "Extraneous references will get cleaned up when they're no longer in use." Except when they don't, such as when you use shared memory, open files, asyncio tasks, etc. Python has the same ownership problems like languages like C++ but without good tools to address them. If everything could be solved with a shared pointer that would be great, but it can't, which is why you have things like move semantics. GC is useful but doesn't solve everything.